# Accessing a Remote mongo database hosted in AWS using spring boot application

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

Recently I have created a spring boot application and then I spin up a new aws ec2 instance and installed mongodb in there. I have enabled port 27017 in the security group. When I'm trying to connect I'm getting the following exception:

> com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket    at
>   com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
>   ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]   at
>   com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
>   ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]   at
>   com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113)
>   ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]

My properties are the following:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host= ipaddress
spring.data.mongodb.port= 27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
```

Comment: is your `mongod` (mongo daemon) up and running ?

Comment: Yes. It's running.

Comment: And you tried connecting to the db with mongo shell?

Comment: Yeah. I can connect from shell. When i'm trying to connect from locally using spring boot application it give above error.